# QQ plots: comparing multiple variables to each other in a single figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I want to make a matrix of QQ plots like the one posted here[image] [Sample set QQ plot comparing different elements to each other] . Below is a condensed version of my data frame.  For each scan (a-c), I want a QQ plot to compare the grain size (numerical values below the element names) for each chemical element (s, fe, cr, zr) to each other. Because I have many scans, I will need to make this matrix of QQ plots multiple times.
I am pretty new to R so specific code to help me make these plots would be appreciated.
Thank you

```r
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(GGally)
print(df, n = 27)

   scan  grain     s    fe    cr    zr
 1 a         1    22    21    13    25
 2 a         2    33    31    23    35
 3 a         3    44    41    45    45
 4 a         4    55    51    56    56
 5 a         5    66    61    67    65
 6 a         6    66    71    78    75
 7 a         7    77    81    89    85
 8 a         8    88    82    97    95
 9 a         9    92    93    72    97
10 b         1    23    22    14    26
11 b         2    34    32    24    36
12 b         3    45    42    46    46
13 b         4    56    52    57    57
14 b         5    67    62    68    66
15 b         6    67    72    79    76
16 b         7    78    82    90    86
17 b         8    89    83    98    96
18 b         9    93    94    73    98
19 c         1    24    23    15    27
20 c         2    35    33    25    37
21 c         3    46    43    47    47
22 c         4    57    53    58    58
23 c         5    68    63    69    67
24 c         6    68    73    80    77
25 c         7    79    83    91    87
26 c         8    90    84    99    97
27 c         9    94    95    74    99
```

I have used

```r
ggplot( aes(sample = diameter, color = element, shape = element, )) + 
  stat_qq() + 
  stat_qq_line() +  
  facet_wrap(~ scan, nrow = 3)
```

to compare each element to the theoretical quantile, but not to each other element.

I tried using `GGally` with `ggpairs(df, columns = 3:6)` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH1mt.png) This made a matrix, but I can’t figure out how to make each plot a QQ plot

[image: ggpairs figure comparing elements, but not as a QQ plot].

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?
If yes, this type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

With the data in long format, map `value` to the `sample` aesthetic then plot by `name` (with `facet_wrap`).

```r
library(ggplot2)

df1 |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(s:zr) |>
  ggplot(aes(sample = value)) +
  geom_qq() +
  geom_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ name)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-29 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```
df1 <- 
  structure(list(
    scan = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
             "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), 
    grain = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
              7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
    s = c(22L, 33L, 44L, 55L, 66L, 66L, 77L, 88L, 92L, 23L, 34L, 45L, 56L, 
          67L, 67L, 78L, 89L, 93L, 24L, 35L, 46L, 57L, 68L, 68L, 79L, 90L, 94L), 
    fe = c(21L, 31L, 41L, 51L, 61L, 71L, 81L, 82L, 93L, 22L, 32L, 42L, 
           52L, 62L, 72L, 82L, 83L, 94L, 23L, 33L, 43L, 53L, 63L, 73L, 83L, 84L, 95L), 
    cr = c(13L, 23L, 45L, 56L, 67L, 78L, 89L, 97L, 72L, 14L, 24L, 46L, 57L, 68L, 
           79L, 90L, 98L, 73L, 15L, 25L, 47L, 58L, 69L, 80L, 91L, 99L, 74L), 
    zr = c(25L, 35L, 45L, 56L, 65L, 75L, 85L, 95L, 97L, 26L, 36L, 46L, 57L, 66L, 
           76L, 86L, 96L, 98L, 27L, 37L, 47L, 58L, 67L, 77L, 87L, 97L, 99L)), 
    class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                  "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
                  "23", "24", "25", "26", "27"))
```

Comment: Thank you, Rui, for the suggestion.  I added a new image that failed to upload the first time that should help.  To answer your question, no, I am not looking to compare each element to a normal distribution, but compare each element to the other elements in each scan: s compared to fe, cr, and zr; fe compared to cr and zr; and cr to zr.  I am familiar with pivoting longer if needed. I hope that helps.